# how to make one sql query asking for many rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such table (example and only part of it):

```
    node_id | k | v
    123 | addr:housenumber | 50
    123 | addr:street | Kingsway
    123 | addr:city | London
    123 | (some other stuff) | .....
    100 | addr:housenumber | 121
    100 | addr:street | Edmund St
    100 | addr:city | London
```

I want to find in this table using one query if there exist e.g. London, Kingsway 50 and what's its node_id. How to make such query and is it even possible? How to deal with such problem?

pseudocode:

```
SELECT node_id WHERE (k == 'addr:city') == 'London' AND (k == 'addr:street') == 'Kingsway' AND (k == 'addr:housenumber') == '50' AND for all node_id the same
```

Schema for database: http://pastebin.com/Yigjt77f, my table node_tags.

Comment: Curious, what is this table's PK? A composite of node_id and K or V?

Comment: What is `(k == addr:city)` supposed to mean? This is not a valid SQL expression.

Comment: Also what flavor of SQL is this?

Comment: @TYH this is postgresql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know this, is just pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use self-joins like this:

```
SELECT n1.node_id FROM node_tags n1
INNER JOIN node_tags n2 ON n1.node_id = n2.node_id
INNER JOIN node_tags n3 ON n1.node_id = n3.node_id
WHERE n1.k = 'addr:housenumber' AND n1.v = '50'
AND n2.k = 'addr:street' AND n2.v = 'Kingsway'
AND n3.k = 'addr:city' AND n3.v = 'London'
```

There might be better ways of doing this with PostgreSQL but I'm not that familiar with that DBMS.

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/03b3c/1).